# scrape username from tweets using regex

Tags: php, regex

Here I get tweet text:

```
RT @ChunautiSharma: "@AswalSurendra: @aartic02 @gulpanag ji campaigns in bus http://example.com/wl42nt5dds"
```

I want to scrape first user name using regex to store in variable.
How to do this?

In above text `ChunautiSharma` should be scraped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) for this. Use this regex -

```
@(.*?):
```

Demo of the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/jQ0iF6).
Testing this in PHP-

```
$regex = "/@(.*?):/";
$str    = 'RT @ChunautiSharma: "@AswalSurendra: @aartic02 @gulpanag ji campaigns in bus http://t.co/wl42nt5dds"';
if(preg_match($regex, $str, $match)){
    echo $match[1];
}
//OUTPUT - ChunautiSharma
```

Comment: what should I do to print only `ChunautiSharma` nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=@)(\w+)
```

Example on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/sR9rJ3)

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_match` and store it into `$m`

```
preg_match("/@([^:]+)/", $twitter, $m);
print $m[1] ;
```

or, using `preg_replace` to push directly into the `$name`

```
$name = preg_replace("/.*?@([^:]+):.*/", "$1", $twitter);
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not stop after username completed. It includes remaining text too

Answer (score 0):

With the `\K` feature (this feature removes all on the left from match result):

```
if (preg_match('~@\K[^\s:]+~', $str, $match))
    echo $match[0];
```